# Is this inequality in $L^p(\Omega)$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set and $u\in L^p(\Omega)$ with $p >1$. Let $\Omega^{\prime} = \left\lbrace x\in\Omega \mid u(x) >k\right\rbrace$ where $k$ denotes a positive constant such that $k>1$. It is true that
$$\Vert u -k\Vert_{L^p(\Omega^{\prime})}\leq \Vert u\Vert_{L^p(\Omega^{\prime})}?$$
How could I proceed? Thank You in adcvance!

Comment: $0 \le u(x) - k \le u(x)$ on this set, so $|u(x)-k| \le |u(x)|$ and thus $|u(x)-k|^p \le |u(x)|^p$ since $p > 1$.

Comment: So the inequality holds true. Thank you a lot!